# How to generate empty closed element use XMLGenerator?

Tags: python, xml, django

In django,

```
addQuickElement(name,content,attr)
```

generates XML like this

```
<name attr="attr">content</name>
```

While I want to generate

```
<name attr="attr" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't specify the `contents` argument.

For reference, this is `django/utils/xmlutils.py`:

```
"""
Utilities for XML generation/parsing.
"""

from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator

class SimplerXMLGenerator(XMLGenerator):
    def addQuickElement(self, name, contents=None, attrs=None):
        "Convenience method for adding an element with no children"
        if attrs is None: attrs = {}
        self.startElement(name, attrs)
        if contents is not None:
            self.characters(contents)
        self.endElement(name)
```

You can see here that you just need to not specify `contents`, and so you can do `x.addQuickElement(name, attrs=attrs)`.

(A quick look at XMLGenerator indicates this will still produce an end-tag, rather than a self-closing tag. In Python 3.2 an argument `short_empty_elements` was added to `XMLGenerator.__init__`, but Django isn't still only compatible with Python 2.x. If you care about getting short tags, take a look at the `xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator.startElement` implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some general advice for such a situation, targetted at getting you moving again with minimal delay:

Step 1: Try something plausible. In this case:

```
addQuickElement(name, None, attr)
```

Step 2: Use the help, for example:

```
>>> help(whatever.addQuickElement)
Help on function addQuickElement in module whatever:

addQuickElement(self, name, contents=None, attrs=None)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Step 3: Read The Fantastic Manual

Step 4: Ask a question on a forum like this one

Comment: No such content in the Manual.

Comment: @SuYanqian: I'm sorry; I should have said "If Step 1 works, there is no need to try Steps 2 and 3".

Comment: Step 2b: Read the Even More Complete Code. It'll tell you *exactly* what it does.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Agreed, if you have any code ... some packages appear to use eggs containing only .pyc files.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I had read the source code and tried to code some examples before I asked this question but I still didn't know a method to generator format like `<name attr="attr" />`.

Comment: +1 for `help()`. It's easy to forget to try it when working with Django, but with most things you can still do it in a shell...